# Getting the file path after select file from storage

Tags: android, upload, android-storage

Im trying to make upload picture (later also video) android application. So I want to get file image from storage, then show in imageView, then within button press it will upload to server.

I stumble upon problem the image path is not exist, not sure why. here my code:
button to get image from device:

```
buttonUploadPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media
                    .EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            i.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_IMAGE);
        }
    });
```

my on activity result code:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

            String filename = imageUri.getPath();
            destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), filename + ".jpg");
            imagePath = destination.getAbsolutePath();
            Log.e(LOG, "imagePath: " + imagePath);

            setcardPic.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            buttonSubmitPhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

i got image path from there, but its not the correct name, it gives me like: /storage/emulated/0/external/images/media/298.jpg, the actual filename is like cherry.jpg

here my upload button code:

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;
    Log.e(LOG, "fileName :" + fileName);
    showUploadButton = false; //revert upload button to hidden
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    Log.e(LOG, "running upload file :" + fileName);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e(LOG, "Source File not exist :" + imagePath);
        return 0;
    } else { ... (upload to server this part is working)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
String path = getRealPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(), imageUri);
```

Where the function is

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this may help you. this will return the original path of the file for you.

Comment: this is great! it works perfectly! thanks! i can't check its as answered, i need to wait 4 mins, ill check soon

Comment: Happy to hear that . Happy coding.